# Creating `CMSampleBufferRef` from a .mov file

Tags: ios, ios8, video-capture, cmsamplebufferref

My app captures a video clip for 3 seconds, and programmatically I want to create a 15 sec clip from recorded 3 sec clip by looping it 5 times. And finally have to save 15 sec clip in CameraRoll.

I have got my 3 sec video clip via `AVCaptureMovieFileOutput` and I have its `NSURL` from delegate which is currently in `NSTemporaryDirectory()`.

I am using `AVAssetWriterInput` for looping it. But it ask for `CMSampleBufferRef` like :

```
[writerInput appendSampleBuffer:sampleBuffer];
```

How will I gee this `CMSampleBufferRef` from video in NSTemporaryDirectory() ?

I have seen code for converting `UIImage` to `CMSampleBufferRef`, but I can find any for video file.

Any suggestion will be helpful. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I fixed my problem using `AVMutableComposition`. Here is my code :

```
AVMutableComposition *mixComposition = [AVMutableComposition new];
AVMutableCompositionTrack *mutableCompVideoTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];

AVURLAsset *videoAsset = [[AVURLAsset alloc]initWithURL:3SecFileURL options:nil];
CMTimeRange video_timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, [videoAsset duration]);

CGAffineTransform rotationTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2);
[mutableCompVideoTrack setPreferredTransform:rotationTransform];

CMTime currentCMTime = kCMTimeZero;

for (NSInteger count = 0 ; count < 5 ; count++)
{
    [mutableCompVideoTrack insertTimeRange:video_timeRange ofTrack:[[videoAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0] atTime:currentCMTime error:nil];
    currentCMTime = CMTimeAdd(currentCMTime, [videoAsset duration]);
}

NSString *fullMoviePath = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:[@"moviefull" stringByAppendingPathExtension:@"mov"]];
NSURL *finalVideoFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:fullMoviePath];

AVAssetExportSession *exportSession = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:mixComposition presetName:AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough];
[exportSession setOutputFileType:AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie];
[exportSession setOutputURL:finalVideoFileURL];

CMTimeValue val = [mixComposition duration].value;
CMTime start = CMTimeMake(0, 1);
CMTime duration = CMTimeMake(val, 1);
CMTimeRange range = CMTimeRangeMake(start, duration);
[exportSession setTimeRange:range];

[exportSession exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{

    switch ([exportSession status])
    {
        case AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed:
        {
            NSLog(@"Export failed: %@ %@", [[exportSession error] localizedDescription], [[exportSession error]debugDescription]);
        }
        case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCancelled:
        {
            NSLog(@"Export canceled");
            break;
        }
        case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted:
        {
            NSLog(@"Export complete!");
        }

        default:    NSLog(@"default");
    }
}];
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at AVAssetReader, this can return an CMSampleBufferRef. Keep in mind, you'll need to manipulate the timestamp for your approach to work.